# how to properly construct a Joi validation for a field returning a function

Tags: typescript, validation, joi

I'm trying to building Joi schema validation for:

```
type Toy = {
id: string;
codeName: (nameFormat?: string) => string;
price: number;
}
```

The problem is with the validation of `codeName`.
I don't know how to represent that the `codeName` is a function with an optional parameter (type string) that returns a string.
And the codeName field is actually a required field

I tried to work out a solution with documentation - no grater result
I didn't found any convergent topics on Stack Overflow and other

My project is using Joi in ver 14
I will be grateful for your help

And What I trying to build when I speak about schema:
For Example

```
type CarSchema = {
mark: Joi.string().required(),
color: Joi.string().required(),
price: Joi.number().required(),
accessories: Joi.string().optional(),
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `Joi.function`?

Comment: Yes in my version of Joi is called `func`.

If You will use that You will be able to specify the number of arguments,
but I haven't figured out how to pass further parts like the argument type or the return type

Comment: You can't assert on argument or return types since there's no RTTI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best you can do is:

```
export const toySchema = Joi.object({
  id: Joi.string(),
  codeName: Joi.func().minArity(0).maxArity(1),
  price: Joi.number(),
});
```

Since JavaScript has no notion of type, and TypeScript does not provide RTTI, there's no way for you to check either the types of the expected arguments of a function, or the return type.